# Fastest way to do many, many different gsub operations?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am converting tens of thousands of documents from one markup format (apparently some descendant of RUNOFF for which I have minimal documentation) into something that I can feed to LaTeX.  Part of this process involves searching each document for each string that had special meaning in the old markup format and replacing it with the appropriate string for LaTeX.  There are hundreds of these.  My two thoughts so far are to do each as a separate gsub or to make a gsub with a regex that will match (by way of ORing) many of the symbols and then passing the match off to method with a big case statement that will pass back the appropriate substitution.  On the face of it the second way reduces the number of times the each document must be scanned but the overhead of the ORs within the regex may be more costly.  Does anyone have an idea of which is the better approach or if I have missed a good approach?

Here are examples of the two ways I have described.  They may be imperfect.  Just trying to get my point across.

Method 1:

```
output.gsub!(/a<-"/, '\\"{a}') # ä
output.gsub!(/a<-^/, '\\^{a}') # â
output.gsub!(/a<-~/, '\\~{a}') # ã
...etc
```

Method 2:

```
output.gsub!(/a<-"|a<-^|a<-~|etc/) {|match| convert_symbol(match)}

def convert_symbol(input)
  case match
  when 'a<-"'
    '\\"{a}' # ä
  when "a<-^"
    '\\^{a}' # â
  when "a<-~"
    '\\~{a}' # ã
  when 'etc'
    '\\LaTeX...etc'
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not benchmark both on a few files and see which is faster?

Comment: Yes, that is the best suggestion. Sooo...I did benchmarks on both of my methods and Mori's and it turns out that they are all nearly identical in speed.  This is actually kinda surprising.  I tried it multiple times using a multiple sample inputs just to be sure.

So, it is just a matter of which is easiest to read and maintain...

Answer (score 8):

Wow, that's a lot of documents. But I think if I were doing it, I would not worry about how efficient the program is. Computers are fast and cheap and don't mind running all night.

Actually, I don't think I would open code (wire into the program) the regex expressions in the general case. I think I would put the substitutions into a flat or YAML file and only build into the program those expressions or features where state is required.

So if I needed to remember a token I might build the expression in, or perhaps flag it in a YAML file filled with transcoding expressions ... I would worry most about how well and how nicely my program is structured. I would try to minimize my time fiddling with it and running tests, and not worry, at least at first, about how fast it runs.

In particular, this program, once finished, only runs once for each document. So it's not really a good candidate for careful speed optimization. Furthermore, since it runs once and you must then forever live with its decisions, I would think that your focus should be on fidelity and not speed.

Comment: Normally I would agree but in this case speed is a consideration.  An explanation of why would take more space than is allowed here (though I wouldn't mind explaining).  Note also that the replacements (or at least groups of them) have to be ordered in order for the translation to occur properly. Because I lack the complete specification for the input format I am having to deduce what needs to be done. This means the ordering of translation steps may change as new reqs are "discovered". Its a challenge and a PITA. Appreciate the suggestions...I'm a jr developer and every angle helps my head.

Comment: Good luck! Btw, if you posted some of the original markup, I'm sure we could identify the format.

Answer (score 6):

```
{ /a<-"/ => '\\"{a}', 
  ... 
}.each { |find, replace| output.gsub! find, replace }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these all of the same general format?  Then you could simply

```
output.gsub!(/([aeiouy])<-(["~^])/, '\\\2{\1}')
```

... assuming Ruby has backreferences in `\1`, `\2` etc (sorry, not too familiar with the language).

Comment: they are not all of the same general format.  large swaths are...but even larger swaths are not.